Specify working-directory in a multi-job that uses an external workflow
I'm having trouble with the following scenario:
I have a project which contains two sub-projects. I want to execute a GitHub action which uses a reusable workflow. I need to separate jobs for this, for which I need to specify the respective directory. I can't seem to figure out the correct syntax for this though, I've already checked the documentation, but this combination of having two jobs with different working directories doesn't seem to work - IntelliJ is already complaining about 'working-directory' being there.
Also
defaults:
  run:
    working-directory: ./james-frontend

doesn't work
Here's my example:
name: Scan for backend and frontend

on:
  schedule:
    - cron: '0 0 * * SAT'
  push:
    paths:
      - 'backend/**'
      - 'frontend/**'
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  scan-backend:
    name: Backend
    working-directory: ./backend
    uses: test-project/workflows/.github/workflows/scan.yml@main
    with:
      project-name: 'backend'
      runner-type: 'medium'
    secrets:
      SCANTOKEN: ${{ secrets.SCANTOKEN }}
      ARTIFACTORY_USER: ${{ secrets.ARTIFACTORY_USER }}
      ARTIFACTORY_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.ARTIFACTORY_TOKEN }}

  scan-frontend:
    name: Frontend
    working-directory: ./frontend
    uses: test-project/workflows/.github/workflows/scan.yml@main
    with:
      project-name: 'backend'
      runner-type: 'medium'
    secrets:
      SCANTOKEN: ${{ secrets.SCANTOKEN }}
      ARTIFACTORY_USER: ${{ secrets.ARTIFACTORY_USER }}
      ARTIFACTORY_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.ARTIFACTORY_TOKEN }}

In another project, where there's only one actual project, I can use the following syntax and it works (working-directory does not need to be specified, because it's already in the actual project dir):
name: Scan

on:
  schedule:
    - cron: '0 0 * * SAT'
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  call-scan:
    uses: test-project/workflows/.github/workflows/scan.yml@main
    with:
      project-name: 'my-project'
      runner-type: 'medium'
    secrets:
      SCANTOKEN: ${{ secrets.SCANTOKEN }}
      ARTIFACTORY_USER: ${{ secrets.ARTIFACTORY_USER }}
      ARTIFACTORY_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.ARTIFACTORY_TOKEN }}

